# Target id of a bootstrap modal to stop video from playing when modal is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, video

I have a video into a bootstrap modal form that is opened on click. Now when i close the modal i want that video to stop playing.
I've manage to do some javascript to do that but instead of stopping the the video i want it stops all the video from that page.

How can i target in the script below only the ID of the modal that i want to be stoped from playing?

```
<script>
    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $('video').trigger('pause');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to pause the video

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
  $('#ModalId').find('video').get(0).pause()
});
```

The [pause()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp) method halts (pauses) the currently playing audio or video.

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/NpgD5/956/)**

Comment: The script works perfectly but i want to target and stop only the video from the modal with #myModal ID not the outer videos that are autoplaying in the same page.

Comment: @AdrianAdr use your modal id instead of 'video'

Answer (score 0):

the function that you bind is passing an argument that contain a target property that represent the modal `HTMLElement`

try this:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function (event) {
  $(event.target, ' video').trigger('pause');
});
```